# Send data to mysql form multiple forms

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm struggling to send multiple records of user to my mysql databse. I'm trying to create a small registration app where users pick events and how many people they want to register on it.

Then i return  specific number of registration forms depending on the users pick. Next i want send all this data to my table.

Here is my code so far

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$persons = $_POST['person_number'];
$event = $_POST['event'];

for ($i=1; $i <= $persons; $i++) {
    echo "<b>Uczestnik #" . $i;
    $content = "<form action='thankyou.php' method='post' />";
    $content .= "<div class='form-group'>
    <label for='Imię'>Imię</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='name' />
    </div>";
    $content .= "<div class='form-group'>
    <label for='Nazwisko'>Nazwisko</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='last-name' />
    </div>";
    $content .= "<div class='form-group'>
    <label for='email'>Adres Email</label>
    <input type='email' class='form-control' name='email' />
    </div>";

    echo $content;

     }
    echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='submit2>Rejsestruje się</button>";
    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Also i have another question ,since my users pick few events i store their pick and array and later on post it to form page.  How can i separate it and give as input to table query so for example 10 users could go to room a and 20 to room b ?

```
                <input type="checkbox" class="ck" name="event[]" id="event" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>"><span>Wybierz</span>
```

Thank you fo much for all your support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer Of first Question:-

//In Thankyou.php Please write These code of lines

```
$flag = 0;
if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
  if(count($_POST['name']) > 0) {  
    for($k=0;$k<=count($_POST['name']);$k++) {
        if(!empty($_POST['name'][$k])) {
            $insert = "insert into users set
                       name = '".$_POST['name'][$k]."',
                       last_name = '".$_POST['last_name'][$k]."',
                       email = '".$_POST['email'][$k]."'";
             mysql_query($insert);
            $flag++;
        } 

     }    
  } 
   echo "Total number of persons has been inserted is : ". $flag;
   exit;
}



//Main Page Content
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$persons = $_POST['person_number'];
$event = $_POST['event'];
$content = "<form  method='post' />";
for ($i=1; $i <= $persons; $i++) {
    $content .= "<div><b>Uczestnik #" . $i.'</div>';    
    $content .= "<div class='form-group'>
    <label for='Imię'>Imię</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='name[]' />
    </div>";
    $content .= "<div class='form-group'>
    <label for='Nazwisko'>Nazwisko</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='last_name[]' />
    </div>";
    $content .= "<div class='form-group'>
    <label for='email'>Adres Email</label>
    <input type='email' class='form-control' name='email[]' />
    </div>";  
    $content .="<br>";
     }  

     $content .="<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='submit2' value='Rejsestruje się'>";
     $content .="</form>";
     echo $content;
}
```